# Citation of Standard Industrial Classification (SIC) in academic writing

Tags: abbreviations, citation, academia

I am referring to companies in a certain SIC classification and I am not sure if it's necessary to add a proper citation, when first mentioning the SIC classification, to the "Occupational Safety & Health Administration, U.S. Department of Labor (1987)" or if it is sufficient to add a footnote on this and perhaps add a nocite entry into the references.
The entry in the references would look like this and is based on a @misc bibtex entry.

Occupational Safety & Health Administration, U.S. Department of Labor (1987): SIC description for 1311. Accessed: 2016-03-22.

I am just unsure if this is perhaps common knowledge and doesn't need an own citation.

Comment: Have you looked at other papers to see what they do? I found [this one](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/40968777.pdf) and it doesn't use a reference for SIC.

Comment: Another thought, the C in SIC stands for classification already, so no need to say SIC _classification_. Say SIC, or SIC category maybe. Is the category odd and you want to make sure we know it's not just your own invention? If not, who cares it's an SIC?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I only made that mistake in the question. ;-) 
I've now checked some more articles and it appears to be some kind of common knowledge, which is not explicitly cited in the references. Thanks for the help.